# BasePage Requests return null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class

I'm trying to implement a base class which contains code to be used throughout the site into one of my layouts. The code I have used for this is:

```
Site.BasePage bp = new Site.BasePage();
```

This is fine and allows me to access the methods using `bp`, however, if I try to access a method using the `Request` function I get a nullreferenceexception, as `Request` is null. One example of this is where I am doing `Request.Cookies["cookiename"]`.

Comment: So the BasePage isnt really the base class of a view, but a field initialized somewhere else? I guess at a minimum you would need to set the `ViewContext` property of `bp`, check the ConfigurePage method [on the source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/WebViewPage.cs)

Comment: How are you using the above code? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @NightOwl888 The above code is placed in a code block at the top of my one of my Layout views. I need to access `bp`'s methods later on in the same view.

Comment: I still don't understand. How does the Request fit in the picture? I don't see how Site.BasePage relates in any way to Request.Cookies. Show some more code, or we cannot help you.